# How to create offline map with routing in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, openstreetmap

I want to create app with offline maps which support offline routing, it will be good if tiles for maps create from vector file and bundl it in apk, is any idea how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [mapsforge](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge) for a possible solution or at [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) in general in the OSM wiki.

Comment: Mapsforge has nothing to do with routing